# refactoring error in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have one parent project with its 4 child (project) in maven.But when i am going to execute that one.it gives following plugin in error.How could i resolve this error??plz help me

```
1.Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 
2.plug in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid Menu extension


Parent project pom.xml is

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.te.sss</groupId>
      <artifactId>iin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <name>iin</name>
      <description>parent</description>
      <modules>
      <module>../commons</module>
      <module>../dao</module>
      <module>../core</module>
      <module>../web</module>
      </modules>  
    </project>
```

Comment: What exactly are you executing?

Comment: srry  i am not executing actually bulid  maven  parent project with its child and also perform maven cleaning operation

Comment: someone explain me what is meaning of 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' in brief